# Beforeload event not firing when stores have a server proxy

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an override as such:

```
//Renabled the refresh buttons once these stores have loaded data OK...
Ext.define('App.overrides.data.Store', {
    override: 'Ext.data.Store',
    onProxyLoad: function () {
        switch (this.storeId) {
            case 'store1':
            case 'store2':
            case 'store3':
            case 'store4':
            case 'store5':
                Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=mainRefreshButton]').setDisabled(false);
                Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=refreshButton]').setDisabled(false);
                Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=refreshAccountButton]').setDisabled(false);
                break;
        }
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    listeners: {
         beforeload: function (store, operation, opts) {
            //debugger;
            switch (store.storeId) {
                case 'store1':
                case 'store2':
                case 'store3':
                case 'store4':
                case 'store5':
                    Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=mainRefreshButton]').setDisabled(true);
                    Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=refreshButton]').setDisabled(true);
                    Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=refreshAccountButton]').setDisabled(true);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

The `onProxyLoad` override works fine with server proxies. But the `beforeload` listeners only fires for memory stores that I load right away (store with fixed data in them such as "Yes"/"No" array data)

When I do `store1.reload()` (a store with a server proxy), I'm never reaching the listener code.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

**NB**: I have validated the override runs BEFORE the store1/2/3/4/5 is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the `load` method like such:

```js
//Renabled the refresh buttons once these stores have loaded data OK...
Ext.define('App.overrides.data.Store', {
  override: 'Ext.data.Store',
  onProxyLoad: function() {
    switch (this.storeId) {
      case 'store1':
      case 'store2':
      case 'store3':
      case 'store4':
      case 'store5':
        Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=mainRefreshButton]').setDisabled(false);
        Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=refreshButton]').setDisabled(false);
        Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=refreshAccountButton]').setDisabled(false);
        break;
    }
    this.callParent(arguments);
  },
  load: function() {
    switch (store.storeId) {
      case 'store1':
      case 'store2':
      case 'store3':
      case 'store4':
      case 'store5':
        Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=mainRefreshButton]').setDisabled(true);
        Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=refreshButton]').setDisabled(true);
        Utils.getCmp('button[itemId=refreshAccountButton]').setDisabled(true);
        break;
    }
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
```

Now I'm catching every load/reload of every store.